# Connecting ethernet and wifi on raspberry

Tags: networking

I'm trying to get rpi to connect to the Internet via wifi (wlan0) - it will connect to a mobile hotspot. It also has to have wired connection (eth0) to a router that is not connected to the Internet.

My desktop PC is also connected to the router. I'm doing this so that I can access a web application running on rpi from my desktop pc, while rpi has its own wifi connection to the Internet.

I understand that this is a bit strange, but this is the only way that I can run  local web applications in my office without hopefully breaking any security policies.

I've followed the instructions on [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/setting-up-wifi-and-ethernet). My rpi can only ping www.google.com but not my router 192.168.1.1.

I've been tinkering around for over two hours now but I still can't have it so that rpi will respond when I ping from my desktop pc, and at the same time google will respond when I ping www.google.com from rpi.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could give me a hand on this...

Comment: does this work from the Pi - `ping -I eth0 192.168.1.1` ? <-- that is a capital i and not a lowercase l before eth0...What IP address does eth0 have ?

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange! Please don't add "thanks" to your question. Upvote answers you like, this  is the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange way of saying thank you.

Comment: What does `netstat -r` show?

Comment: @Lawrence: eth0 has 192.168.1.42. Entering `ping -I eth0 192.168.1.1` gives me the following response: "from 192.168.1.42 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable"

Comment: what does the command `route` output ?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn: `netstat -r` shows http://imgur.com/19g4KAs

Comment: @Lawrence: `route` outputs the same thing that `netstat -r` outputs. http://imgur.com/19g4KAs

Comment: Oops, didn't notice HeatfanJohn's comment. If you bring down the wlan interface temporarily, can you ping the router ?

Comment: @Lawrence: I still get "Destination Host Unreachable" message when I ping the router. All the configuration settings are exactly the same as described on this post (except for ssid and pass of course): (http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/setting-up-wifi-and-ethernet)

Comment: How about if you disconnect the wifi adapter, then reboot and try and ping the router ?

Comment: @Lawrence: dang it... this is very embarrassing... the ethernet cable was disconnected this whole time! so it's working now. Thank you for taking a look into this!

Comment: Happens to all of us :D

Comment: I am facing the exact same question with you. Could you share with me how you solve it? I want to access my pi through direct ethernet connection while keep the wifi not affected. I don't have an extra router, and just want to visit the web application on my raspberry pi.

Comment: @Ji. Have you solved this issue yet? If so, could you please create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the Q:A ratio up and that would help us a ton. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the USB Wi-fi adapter, I was able to connect RPi to the Internet via a mobile hotspot. It has a wired connection to a router as well. Also, I have a PC connected to the router, which means I can access web applications running on RPi. Please note that just as described in the original post, I was able to accomplish this by following the instructions on [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8851/setting-up-wifi-and-ethernet). Here are the configuration settings that I have on my RPi:

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
ssid="SSID"
scan_ssid=1
proto=RSN
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
pairwise=CCMP TKIP
group=CCMP TKIP
psk="PASSWORD"
id_str="home"
priority=5
}
```

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.42
netmask 255.255.255.0
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
address 192.168.43.142
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 192.168.43.255
gateway 192.168.43.1
iface default inet dhcp
```

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo cat /etc/default/ifplugd

```
INTERFACES="eth0"
HOTPLUG_INTERFACES="eth0"
ARGS="-q -f -u0 -d10 -w -I"
SUSPEND_ACTION="stop"
```

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo cat /etc/rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi
sudo ifplugd eth0 --kill
sudo ifup wlan0
exit 0
```